# Problem with Search Results in WP (not displaying the full posts)

Tags: plugins, search, search-engines

In this momment, in search results appear the post but without categories (I think are hidden) and with the links from posts broken.
I have a piece of code in this theme that i think is responsible for this.
Here is the code:

```
<?php $post_format = get_post_format() or $post_format = 'default'; ?>

<?php if (get_post_type() != 'post' || is_single() || !Website::getThemeOption("format_post/{$post_format}/content/hide")): ?>
    <div class="content clear"><?php
            if (is_search()) {
                $sq = preg_quote(get_search_query(), '/');
                printf('<p>%s</p>', preg_replace("/\b{$sq}\b/i", '<mark class="search">\0</mark>', get_the_content()));

            } else {
                if (has_excerpt() && !is_singular()) {
                    the_excerpt();
                } else {
                    the_content(Website::getThemeOption('post/readmore'));
                }
                if (is_singular()) {
                    $pages = wp_link_pages(array(
                        'before' => '',
                        'after'  => '',
                        'echo'   => false
                    ));
                    if ($pages) {
                        printf('<div class="pagination">%s</div>', preg_replace('/ ([0-9]+)/', ' <span class="current">\1</span>', $pages));
                    }
                }
            }
        ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to display in search results the full post untouched, as he is, without any restriction. This code might be the problem or something else? This theme don't have `category.php` or `search.php` and this code is from `content.php`. Is possible to fix this (maybe with a plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unaware about the code written within the condition for search page. But the following code instead of your one would have to work:

```
if (is_search()) {
                the_content();
            }
```

Try and let me know.