# How to wrap submit button of comment form with div

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template

Is there a way to wrap the submit button with html element while using wordpress function comment_form function.

```
$comments_args = array(
            'id_form'               => 'main-contact-form',
            'class_form'            => 'contact-form',
            'class_submit'          => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg',
            'label_submit'          => 'Add Comment',
            'fields'                =>  $fields,
            'title_reply_before'    => '<div class="message_heading"><h4>',
            'title_reply_after'    => '</h4><p>Make sure you enter the(*)required information where indicate.HTML code is not allowed</p></div>',
            'comment_field' => '
                <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-7">                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div> 
                </div>'

        );

        comment_form($comments_args);
```

I want output code for submit button be like:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use [`comment_form`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) function's **`submit_button`** parameter to change submit button HTML.

Default HTML for `submit_button` is

```
<input name="%1$s" type="submit" id="%2$s" class="%3$s" value="%4$s" />
```

You can change your code like this.

```
$comments_args = array(
   ....

   'submit_button' => '<div class="form-group">
            <input name="%1$s" type="submit" id="%2$s" class="%3$s" value="%4$s" />
        </div>'

   ....
);
```

**Update:**

Regarding `%1$s` , `%2$s` and so on..

If you take a look at [comment_form()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L2111) source, you can see that [`submit_button`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L2340) is going through sprintf like this.

```
$submit_button = sprintf(
  $args['submit_button'],
    esc_attr( $args['name_submit'] ),
    esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ),
    esc_attr( $args['class_submit'] ),
    esc_attr( $args['label_submit'] )
);
```

Comment: It worked well.. Can you explain why you used %1$s, %2$s. I found it useful for custom arguments 'class_submit', 'label_submit'. How actually it works?

Comment: @asisStha That's a thing with [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115931/43098)

Comment: @asisStha, updated the answer to give some idea

Answer (score 5):

Please place below code in your theme's functions.php file and it will wrap the submit button inside div:

```
// define the comment_form_submit_button callback
function filter_comment_form_submit_button( $submit_button, $args ) {
    // make filter magic happen here...
    $submit_before = '<div class="form-group">';
    $submit_after = '</div>';
    return $submit_before . $submit_button . $submit_after;
};

// add the filter
add_filter( 'comment_form_submit_button', 'filter_comment_form_submit_button', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more updated answer:

```
'submit_field' => '<p class="form-submit">%1$s %2$s</p>',
```